# Crear el procedemiento almacenado de mantenimiento de una tabla en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Necesito su ayuda, por favor. Estoy comenzando en Oracle. Quisiera saber cómo hacer el mantenimiento de una tabla, en este caso, de una tabla clientes, básicamente un crud. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
    IdCli                VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL ,
    Nombre               VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ,
    Ruc                  VARCHAR2(11) NOT NULL ,
    Direccion            VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ,
    Estado               VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (IdCli)
);

INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('C0001','MARCOS PEREZ LUIS','10550078987','AV. ARRIOLA 1234 MONTEZ','ACTIVO');
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('C0002','RAMOS SALAS CARMEN','10222587897','AV. CASTILLO 120 LAMPA','BLOQUEADO');
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('C0003','MILAGROS MARTINEZ EDUARDO','10547848757','JR. SALAVERRY 323 SJL','ACTIVO');
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('C0004','QUINTANO TORRES JULIAN','10125458787','AV. BOSQUES 928 TORRES','BLOQUEADO');
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('C0005','TORRES MARTINEZ ELIZABETH','10545878987','AV. DE LA TORRE 245 CENTRO','ACTIVO');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Podés investigar sobre Procedures o Packages, que son básicamente prgramas alojados en la base, y desde donde podes trabajar con los datos de la tabla Cliente.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Crear un paquete que contenga un procedimiento almacenado y función referenciando a una tabla en ORACLE PL/SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529127/crear-un-paquete-que-contenga-un-procedimiento-almacenado-y-funci%c3%b3n-referenciand)