# Crear un paquete que contenga un procedimiento almacenado y función referenciando a una tabla en ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Cómo puedo crear un paquete que contenga un procedimiento almacenado y función referenciando a una tabla, en este caso a una tabla producto, mostraré un ejemplo con mi tabla y sus registros.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO
(
    IdProd               VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL ,
    Nombre               VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ,
    Precio               DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL ,
    Stock                INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Estado               VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (IdProd)
);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTO VALUES('P0001','TV. COLOR LED 42P SMART',1599.99,47,'ACTIVO');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTO VALUES('P0002','TV. COLOR LED 55P SMART',2499.99,0,'BLOQUEADO');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTO VALUES('P0003','REFRIGERADOR 14P3 FROZEN',1299.99,47,'ACTIVO');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTO VALUES('P0004','REFRIGERADOR 16P3 FROZEN',1899.99,0,'BLOQUEADO');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTO VALUES('P0005','LAVADORA 8KG CENTRIFUGADORA LAVA-SECA',2599.99,43,'ACTIVO');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTO VALUES('P0006','LAVADORA 10KG CENTRIFUGADORA LAVA-SECA',2899.99,47,'ACTIVO');
```